# HTML only pulling one xml item into dropdown list

Tags: javascript, html, xml

Here within this function I am trying to populate a drop down menu from items within an xml.  The loop  is only picking up the last item which is Creamed Rice, I have been looking endlessly on why it gets this one and not the rest.

Any input or ideas would be very welcome.
Thanks

```
            function findItem() {
             for (var i=0; i<items.length; i++) {
                  product=items[i].getElementsByTagName("name")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
                  document.getElementById("searchItem").innerHTML=product;
                  searchItem=document.getElementById("searchItem").innerHTML;
                  if (product==searchItem) {
                     id=items[i].getAttribute("id");
                     stockLevel=items[i].getElementsByTagName("numInStock")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
                     price=items[i].getElementsByTagName("price")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;

                     document.getElementById("id").innerHTML=id;
                     document.getElementById("stockLevel").innerHTML=stockLevel;
                     document.getElementById("price").innerHTML=price;
                  }
               }
            }
```

**xml**

```
            <?xml version="1.0"?>
            <stock>

            <item id="101">
               <name>Baked Beans</name>
               <numInStock>20</numInStock>
               <price>0.69</price>
            </item>   

            <item id="102">
               <name>Canned Soup</name>
               <numInStock>35</numInStock>
               <price>0.55</price>
            </item>   

            <item id="103">
               <name>Dog Food</name>
               <numInStock>15</numInStock>
               <price>1.50</price>
            </item>

            <item id="104">
               <name>Sardines</name>
               <numInStock>13</numInStock>
               <price>1.89</price>
            </item>

            <item id="105">
               <name>Creamed Rice</name>
               <numInStock>10</numInStock>
               <price>0.80</price>
            </item>

            </stock>
```

**all of html**

```
            <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html>
            <head>

            <style type="text/css">
            table { border-collapse:collapse }
            td { padding:10px; border:solid #000 1px } 
            td.center { text-align:center }
            td.noBox { border:none }
            </style>

            <script type="text/javascript">

            var items;

            if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
            } else { // IE6, IE5
                var xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            xmlhttp.open("GET","stock.xml",false);
            xmlhttp.send();
            xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML;
            items=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("item"); 


                            function findItem() {
                             for (var i=0; i<items.length; i++) {
                                  product=items[i].getElementsByTagName("name")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
                                  document.getElementById("searchItem").innerHTML=product;
                                  searchItem=document.getElementById("searchItem").innerHTML;
                                  if (product==searchItem) {
                                     id=items[i].getAttribute("id");
                                     stockLevel=items[i].getElementsByTagName("numInStock")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
                                     price=items[i].getElementsByTagName("price")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;

                                     document.getElementById("id").innerHTML=id;
                                     document.getElementById("stockLevel").innerHTML=stockLevel;
                                     document.getElementById("price").innerHTML=price;
                                  }
                               }
                            }   

            </script>
            </head>

            <body>
            <h1>Product list</h1>


            <script type="text/javaScript">
            document.write("<p>There are " + items.length + " items available</p>");
            </script>

            <table>
            <tr><th>id</th><th>Product</th><th>Stock level</th><th>Price</th></tr>

            <tr>
                <td class="noBox" id="id"></td>
                <td>
                <select onClick="findItem()">
                    <option id="searchItem">
                    </option>
                </select>
                </td>
                <td class="center" id="stockLevel"></td>
                <td class="center" id="price"></td>    
            </tr>

            </table>    

            </body>
            </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Without being able to run your code, the problem may be in the following line:

```
document.getElementById("searchItem").innerHTML=product
```

You are always replacing this element, so what is displayed on the page is just the last one.

Comment: I kind of get what you mean, but how would you suggest I go about this?

Comment: @PMG can you post your HTML as well?

Comment: Without writing an example code, you'd need to create one element for each item and *append* each item to a parent element, such as `#searchList`

Comment: I have just added the rest of the HTML

Answer (score 0):

There is only one  entry in your html, how can you expect more to pop up.

Comment: I am not sure how to add more, I tried making more option tags but it just displayed blank lines within the drop down menu.